# Devo utilizar GUID ou int como chave primária?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, guid

Estou prestes a começar um novo projeto em MVC 4 com Entity Framework, pesquisando encontrei vários exemplos aqui no SOpt de models que utilizam GUID como ID e algumas dúvidas me surgiram:

Qual a vantagem de se utilizar GUID como chave primária?

É viável utilizar em um projeto pequeno?

Existem contras na utilização de GUID?

Comment: Aqui é um caso onde infelizmente, por uma questão de tempo e moda, as respostas corretas (que destacam a razão de evitar o overhead do GUID quando não precisar de fato dele - o que é quase sempre) perderam o destaque e ficaram mais pra baixo.

Comment: Documentação **da Microsoft**, link numa das respostas abaixo: _Já que os valores de GUIDs são longos e obscuros, eles não são significativos para os usuários. Se GUIDs gerados aleatoriamente forem usados para valores de chave e você inserir muitas linhas, você obterá E/S aleatórias em seus índices, o que poderá afetar negativamente o desempenho. Os GUIDs também são relativamente grandes quando comparados a outros tipos de dados. Em geral, recomendamos o **uso de GUIDs apenas em cenários muito restritos**, para os quais nenhum outro tipo de dados é adequado._

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Vantagem de utilizar GUID:

Gera um valor único em cada tabela e cada banco de dados e isso permite fácil fusão/merge/migração de registros entre bancos de dados diferentes.
Você pode gerar seus IDs na aplicação sem precisar do banco de dados, exemplo:

```
Guid meuNovoGuid;
meuNovoGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Desvantagens de utilizar GUID:

Vejo o GUID como um número grande e desnecessário, isso pode ter sérias implicações de desempenho e de armazenamento, se você não tiver cuidado.
Principalmente para o caso de um aplicativo Asp.Net MVC, onde temos url's amigáveis é muito mais simples termos:

`http:\\localhost\Cliente\Detalhes\1234` em vez de `http:\\localhost\Cliente\Detalhes\031E9502-E283-4F87-9049-CE0E5C76B658`

Usando o int em sua aplicação Asp.Net MVC será mais fácil de entender, exibir esses IDs para os usuários em grids por exemplo e você terá uma performance melhor também.

Comment: Peço desculpas, mas não concordo com você. Há várias maneiras de fazer URL amigável no ASP.NET MVC, evitando de usar o Id, como passando o nome do cliente, por exemplo. Usar o Id no *slug* do endereço é até um potencial problema de segurança, pois o uso pode ser mal intencionado.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Sim, claro. Mas é muito comum ver esse tipo de URL por aí (acho até que é o mais comum). Achei interessante pontuar o assunto pois é mais simples usar um ID 1234 de Int do que um ID de GUID 031E9502-E283-4F87-9049-CE0E5C76B658

Comment: É mais simples, mas perigoso, e está deixando de ser usado. Alguns clientes meus até pediram pra mudar o *slug* pra descrição ao invés de um Id (seja ele `int`, `bigint` ou `Guid`). Isto seria mais um aspecto da aplicação, e não do banco de dados.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Entendi seu ponto de vista, bem colocado, mas acredito que a segurança e construção de url's com ou sem ID estaria saindo um pouco fora da pergunta. Como é uma aplicação Asp.Net MVC quis apenas demostrar a facilidade de usar o int do que o guid na url ou em um grid por exemplo.

Answer (score 25):

## Qual a vantagem de se utilizar GUID como chave primária?

Vantagens:

- Elimina problemas clássicos de chave primária `IDENTITY`, pois o limite de registros aumenta consideravelmente (mais ou menos 5.316.911.983.139.663.491.615.228.241.121.400.000 registros), e evita lacunas entre Id's;
- Torna imprevisível uma busca humana por dados (sobretudo as mal intencionadas), melhorando a segurança. A busca passa a ser feita por outra coluna, e não por Id, o que pode não ser seguro numa aplicação moderna;

  - Nos exemplos dados em outras respostas, um usuário pode tentar acessar facilmente um registro colocando Id's quaisquer na barra de endereços e fazendo requisições `GET` testando a existência de um registro ou não;
- Retira do banco de dados a responsabilidade pela geração da coluna. A coluna é gerada pela aplicação;
- Elimina quase todos os problemas de concorrência relacionados com inserção e atualização de registros. Os demais podem ser resolvidos com transações explícitas;
- Migrações e junções de dados ficam tremendamente mais simples, visto que não há o problema de reservar faixas de valores para a chave primária;
- Mais natural para Ajax com entidades agregadas e dependentes, porque não há a necessidade de trabalhar com chaves provisórias. A chave gerada na criação do registro pode ser usada na gravação do registro, ou então ser tratada como provisória e substituída ao persistir a entidade principal e suas derivadas.

## É viável utilizar em um projeto pequeno?

É. Não há qualquer problema em utilizar.

## Existem contras na utilização de GUID?

Sim, assim como em qualquer outra escolha do padrão de dados das chaves primárias da sua aplicação:

- [`Guid`s normalmente usam 16 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Definition). Este número pode variar dependendo da implementação, enquanto que o `int` usa 4 bytes e o `bigint` usa 8. Dependendo do volume de dados, o uso de `Guid`s pode aumentar sensivelmente o volume de dados armazenado;

  - É preciso uma ressalva aqui: a diferença não é tão gritante quanto se imagina, sobretudo considerando os volumes de dados suportados pelos serviços de hospedagem atuais.
- O *overhead* de desempenho é na ordem de 10%;
- Dependendo do tamanho da tabela, usar `Guid`s completamente aleatórias pode causar perda de performance se o índice for `clustered`. Isto porque não há um padrão lógico de ordenação para o índice seguir. Uma das alternativas pra isso é colocar algum padrão de sequência na geração da `Guid`, [conforme explicado neste artigo do Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388157/GUIDs-as-fast-primary-keys-under-multiple-database).

Answer (score 17):

Se o seu caso é um projeto pequeno, muito provavelmente não. Claro que não posso falar com precisão, já que "pequeno" não define bem o que é o projeto.

**Normalmente** em projetos pequenos utilizar [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) é uma violação do [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). E é muito comum os projetos violarem este princípio.

Você deve se perguntar quais vantagens você terá no seu projeto. Se você não está vendo um problema que precise do GUID, provavelmente você está querendo buscar a teórica perfeição desnecessária. Tão desnecessária que ela acaba se voltando contra você.

- Seu banco de dados é distribuído?
- Você tem alguma organização fora do normal de como o banco de dados é implantado?
- Ele **realmente** precisará de alguma operação que junte mais de uma tabela com a mesma estrutura e que os IDs podem conflitar?
- Sua aplicação está com problemas de performance na obtenção de um novo ID no banco de dados?
- Existem vários clientes em paralelo precisando criar transações com inserção volumosa de dados que ter o ID disponível antes de acessar o banco traria alguma vantagem?
- Você sabe como usar adequadamente?

Um dos erros mais cometidos é o programador preferir algo que todo mundo diz que é bom e ele não sabe o que fazer com aquilo. Pode até ser bom para os outros que são experientes com aquilo. A melhor ferramenta é aquela que você conhece.

Tem motivos mais técnicos:

- GUIDs são piores para computadores e humanos manipularem/visualizarem;
- consomem espaço demasiado de várias formas;
- e consequentemente piora o desempenho, mesmo que minimamente.

Poderia ser preciosista e dizer que ele não é 100% garantido único. Mas na prática é.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sensacional, sempre apliquei o **YAGNI**, mas não sabia que existia essa nomenclatura, nada melhor que compartilhar conhecimento!

Answer (score 8):

Segundo a Microsoft, só se utiliza GUID em aplicações muito particulares. Esses tipo de dados tem muitas desvantagens:

1 - São 50% mais lentos que o bigint, com relação a busca(não estou considerando joins);
2 - São péssimos para manutenção;
3 - Em relação ao int/bigint ocupam muito espaço.

Você deve avaliar as vantagens e desvantagens. Nos meus projetos só vi desvantagens.

Link Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/comparing-guid-and-uniqueidentifier-values

Answer (score 4):

Tenho usado uma solução alternativa. Usei uma função que gera um id randômico com letras e números com 15 caracteres.
Já fiz testes gerando 1 bilhão de sequênciais em um loop sem repetição.
isso consome menos espaço em tabelas que você sabe que terá menos registros, você pode gerar um id com menos caracteres, ocupando menos espaço.
No meu cenário peço apenas que os id não se repita na tabela, e não no banco inteiro.
O guid nao vai se repetir nunca, facebook/instagram com certeza usa guid para identificar bilhões de os posts diários.

A principal vantagem que vejo nessa técnica para bancos que tem que atender sistemas distribuídos, e que você poderá sempre criar chaves primarias com apenas 1 coluna.
As chaves compostas, tendem a consumir mais espaço e não terem a mesma performance.

Mesmo em tabelas com relação pai filho, na tabela filho crio uma chave com o ID e
outro campo com índice para relacionar com a tabela pai.

Link a função que gera uma chave randômica.
https://showdelphi.com.br/dica-funcao-para-gerar-uma-senha-aleatoria-delphi/

Você pode também optar por um campo bigint e gerar um random somente com números.  random(9999999999)
big int permite um numero monstruoso, gerando um random elevado é improvável que isso se repita.

Answer (score -3):

Pensem offline. Façam usando um decimal (18,0):

20   365 86400  999  99999

12   345 67890  123  45678

Ano com 2 decimais
dia do ano
segundos no dia
milésimos de segundos
Aleatório => Função(ID usuário)

Assim mesmo off-line você terá um código com grande possibilidade de ser único com baixo custo de espaço e processamento (em média no máximo 10%). Depende do horário mundial. E é aleatório.
E são crescentes. A inserção é de baixo custo.
Um numero monstruoso aleatório mexe muito com as tabelas dos índices.
Ao voltar ON LINE se faz a inserção e sincronização.

Se torna independente do SQL. Ou conexão.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).