# Qual a probablidade de se gerar um Guid Repetido?

Tags: c#, .net, guid

Qual a probabilidade de se gerar um Guid Repetido com `Guid.NewGuid()`?

Estou fazendo o upload de inúmeras imagens do meu sistema.

O mesmo será um MultiTenancy, e compartilhará do mesmo Deploy, logo das mesmas pastas.

Eu atribuo o nome das imagens com um `Guid` + extensão(jpg,png ou gif)

Existe alguma probabilidade de gerar um `Guid` já existente?

Comment: rod, não é melhor fazer sequencial?
ou usar os segundos?

Comment: @Joannis se o nome for formado pelos segundos a chance de colisão é real. Duas imagens criadas no mesmo segundo podem colidir o nome.

Comment: Quando faço esse tipo de Upload, uso o DateTime, ou seja passado 1 milésimo seria impossível um numero igual. Exemplo 14/11/2014 16:28:31, deixando apenas números, 14112014162831, como eu disse, impossível repetir este número.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Em 1 milésimo de segundo um computador de 2 GHz faz 2 GHz / 1000 = 2 milhões de ciclos de clock. Tem ciclo demais aí para não haver risco, eu não sei os cálculos exatos, e tem I/O envolvida, além de eventual ocupação desse tempo por outros processos do sistema operacional, mas eu não seria tão categórico em dizer que não há risco de repetição.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Apesar de que cada GUID gerado não possui nenhuma garantia de ser único, o número total de chaves únicas (2<sup>128</sup> ou ~3.4×10<sup>38</sup>) é tão grande que a probabilidade do mesmo número ser gerado duas vezes é muito pequena. Por exemplo, considerando que o Universo Observável contém 5x10<sup>22</sup> estrelas, cada estrela poderia ter ~6.8×10<sup>15</sup> dos seus próprios GUIDs.

Fonte: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Segundo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/184897/221800) no SO há 1% de chance de colisão se gerar 2.600.000.000.000.000.000 GUIDs.

E [nessa outra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1705008/221800) parece mostrar como criar uma colisão. É bem difícil. Demora absurdamente.

[Artigos](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) [relevantes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120523-00/?p=7553&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) do Raymond Chen. E lá tem links para mais uma das [excelentes séries do Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2012/04/24/guid-guide-part-one/).

Algumas pessoas talvez não entendam que GUID é composto por tantas informações distintas que faz um esforço tão grande para ser único que a maioria das outras tentativas que alguém pensar serão piores, inclusive as citadas nesta página. Não estou dizendo que GUID é a melhor solução para o problema real do AP, apenas reforçando a ideia que ele é mais único do que o número frio indica.

Se a Microsoft acha que está bom para ele usar o GUID em muitas aplicações suas para garantir a unicidade, quem sou eu para dizer que não serve?

Falo mais disto [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21930/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: obrigado por responder, sabe me dizer se iria demorar muito se eu fizesse algo como:  while (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) para verificar em muitos arquivos?

Comment: @Rod Esse é um algoritmo O(n). O quanto demora, porém, depende da velocidade (e demandas) do disco, e de quantos arquivos você já tem. O ideal seria guardar essas imagens em um banco de dados e dar uma identidade numérica a cada uma.

Answer (score 7):

Embora a geração de GUID's seja pseudo-aleatória, acho que podemos considerá-la completamente aleatória para um cálculo de guardanapo.

Os caracteres variáveis são 32, sendo que cada um possui 16 valores possíveis.

Isso é mais ou menos (2<sup>4</sup>)<sup>2<sup>5</sup></sup>. Eu esqueci completamente as fórmulas do ensino médio, então joguei (`Math.pow(16, 32)`) no console do navegador e deu algo próximo de 3,4 x (10<sup>38</sup>).

Vou escrever uma aproximação disso por extenso. Temos (relativamente) pouco mais de 3.400.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000 combinações possíveis.

Se você gerar dois GUID's iguais, aproveite e jogue algumas vezes na mega-sena (36.045.979.200 combinações possíveis, só para efeito de comparação).

Comment: Curioso é que estamos acostumados a usar int (Int32) como PK e raramente nos preocupamos com a limitação absurdamente menor do que do GUID. Um Int32 tem 2.147.483.647 valores: ((2^32) / 2) - 1. Dividimos por 2 porque afinal usamos apenas os positivos. Menos 1 porque não utilizamos nem o zero. Já quando falamos em GUID (2^128) automaticamente pensamos na possibilidade de colisão.

Answer (score 2):

Como comentado no chat, e complementado a resposta do Maniero e do Renan.

Usar um GUID, pode ser difícil de gerar uma colisão, porém utilizar um numero desse tamanho, 38 casas, pode trazer problemas, como de espaço, memória, busca, entre outros, claro dependendo da aplicação esses problemas não existem.

Minha solução, utiliza uma biblioteca que gere números pseudoaleatórios, tire um módulo de 5 casa decimais, já é o suficiente o bastante para não se tornar um número previsível, fazendo isto concatena a direita de um número sequencial, assim seus possíveis problemas acima descritos serão mais difícil de acontecer, além de você ter a garantia que não se repetirá nunca.

#### Exemplo

```
0001 numero sequencial
58976 numero gerado aleatoriamente
```

Seu arquivo `000158976.jpeg` por mais que a primeira parte seja previsível a segunda não é.

Olha meu exemplo funcionando

http://ideone.com/BuLnud

```
string g;
    g = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string nome = g.Substring(0, 5);
    nome = x.ToString()+nome;
    Console.WriteLine(nome);
```