# Identificar o smartphone de forma única

Tags: android

Tenho um aplicativo que precisa identificar de forma única um aparelho.

Mesmo que o usuário remova e instale o app novamente, gostaria que o identificador continuasse o mesmo.

No primeiro momento, pensei em usar o IME do aparelho, mas lendo a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids?hl=pt-br), percebi que não é recomendado:

> Recomendamos seguir estes princípios ao trabalhar com os
>   identificadores do Android:
>
> 1: Evite o uso de identificadores de hardware. Identificadores de hardware, como o SSAID (código Android) e o IMEI, podem ser evitados
>   na maioria dos casos de uso sem limitar os recursos necessários.

Gostaria de saber qual é o risco de utilizar o **IME** como identificador único do aparelho?

(Acredito que seja a permissão em tempo de execução solicitada ao usuário)

Existe alguma outra forma de identificar o aparelho de forma única?

Comment: De uma olhada nessa questão: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: Acredito que as políticas dizem para não utilizar o IMEI pois esse pode ser alterado e pode ser inseguro, pois parelhos "chineses" piratas podem ter IMEI de um aparelho não pirata e também existe a possibilidade de alterar o IMEI. Bandidos fazem isso. No próprio link que você postou tem uma solução para seu problema, utilize o MAC do bluetooth ou do wifi do dispositivo, pois é um hardware atrelado fisicamente ao aparelho e é muito mais improvável de ser alterado. Além deles terem identificadores únicos.

Comment: @GuilhermeBatista, o que me quebra é esta parte:  "a partir do Android M, os endereços MAC dos dispositivos locais (por exemplo, Wi-Fi e Bluetooth) não serão disponibilizados via APIs de terceiros"

Comment: Verdade, não me atentei a isso. Esse tipo de coisa é por motivos de segurança para não rastrear usuário entre redes diferentes. (Se souber a rede do usuário você poderia saber o caminho que ele percorre). Então você pode usar o `AndroidID` , porém ele pode mudar caso o usuário faça um reset de fábrica.
Veja se resolve seu problema:`private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID); `
Não esqueça de importar a biblioteca `import android.provider.Settings.Secure;`

Comment: Bem que eu já estava fazendo uma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Utilizando Endereço MAC**

Acredito que as políticas dizem para não utilizar o IMEI pois esse pode ser alterado e pode ser inseguro, pois parelhos "chineses/piratas" podem ter IMEI de um aparelho não pirata e também existe a possibilidade de alterar o IMEI. 
Bandidos fazem isso o tempo todo.

No próprio link que você postou tem uma solução para seu problema, utilize o MAC do bluetooth ou do wifi do dispositivo, pois é um hardware atrelado fisicamente ao aparelho e é muito mais improvável de ser alterado. Além deles terem identificadores únicos.

O problema dessa abordagem é que aparentemente parou de ser disponibilizada após o Android 6.0, porém alguns usuários parecem ter tido sucesso utilizando reflection

```
private static String getBtAddressViaReflection() {
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Object bluetoothManagerService = new Mirror().on(bluetoothAdapter).get().field("mService");
if (bluetoothManagerService == null) {
    Log.w(TAG, "couldn't find bluetoothManagerService");
    return null;
}
Object address = new Mirror().on(bluetoothManagerService).invoke().method("getAddress").withoutArgs();
if (address != null && address instanceof String) {
    Log.w(TAG, "using reflection to get the BT MAC address: " + address);
    return (String) address;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

}

Tem mais informações sobre isso [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377982/get-bluetooth-local-mac-address-in-marshmallow])

---

### **Utilizando Android ID**

Caso a solução do MAC não funcione, existe a possibilidade de usar o Android ID, que é um identificador único para cada usuário, porém ele pode mudar ou retornar Null depois de um reset de fábrica.

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Existem alguns problemas relacionados a essa abordagem, porém parece que a maioria dos problemas foram resolvidos.

---

### **Utilizando o telefone**

> Essa abordagem não deve funcionar em aparelhos que não tenham função
>   de fazer ligações. Ex: Tablets, TVs, Watches e Veículos.

Caso sua solução seja voltada para telefone, você pode utilizar o TelephoneManager e pegar os ids/serial e criar um identificador:

Adicione a permissão no Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Importe as bibliotecas:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
```

E o código...
    final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

```
final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
androidId = "" + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long)tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
String deviceId = deviceUuid.toString();
```

Essa solução deverá retornar algo como `00000000-54b3-e7c7-0000-000046bffd97`.

Para maiores informações veja esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2853253/1469170)

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Perfeito! Ótima resposta!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode atribuir um identificador [GUID](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%BAnico_universal), já que as chances dele se repetir são extremamente baixas.

> Segundo essa resposta no SO há 1% de chance de colisão se gerar 2.600.000.000.000.000.000 GUIDs.

[Referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40525/qual-a-probablidade-de-se-gerar-um-guid-repetido)

Comment: Então, até me ajuda, mas não garante o mesmo quando o usuário remove e reinstala o app

Comment: Hum...
Não pensei nessa hipótese.
Você não sincroniza os dados do app com um bd externo?

Comment: sim, sincronizo !