# Tabela com chave primária que nunca se repete

Tags: mysql, modelagem

Tenho uma tabela `Produto (id, descricao, tipo)` e essa mesma tabela está em três computadores diferentes.

Todos os três gravam dados em sua máquina e de tempos em tempos, enviam os dados para um servidor.

O que ocorre é o seguinte: digamos que o PC1 e o PC2 gravem dados na tabela:

PC1-

```
1, produto1, tipo1
2, produto2, tipo2
3, produto3, tipo3
```

PC2-

```
1, produto4, tipo4
2, produto5, tipo5
3, produto6, tipo6
```

Quando os dados forem enviados para o servidor, estarão +- assim:

```
1, produto1, tipo1
2, produto2, tipo2
3, produto3, tipo3
4, produto4, tipo4
5, produto5, tipo5
6, produto6, tipo6
```

Esses dados serão baixados por todos os demais PCs para atualizar em seus bancos locais, sendo que será gerada confusão com os IDs. Ex:

no PC1 produto4 terá ID 4

no PC2 produto1 terá ID 4

Minha dúvida é: Existe possibilidade de ser gerado um ID que não se repita?

Comment: Dica: use um [GUID](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%9Anico_Global)

Comment: Se em algum momento vai funcionar offline não tem jeito. Criei um id único para cada input e quando for fazer a atualização, use esse id como referencia. É a única forma possível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução padrão para bancos distribuídos assim é o uso de GUID. Algumas pessoas não gostam. Não vou entrar em detalhes porque isso já foi extensivamente respondido aqui:

- [Devo utilizar GUID ou int como chave primária?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21907/101)
- [Como é gerado o GUID (Identificador Único Global)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184538/101)
- [Qual a probablidade de se gerar um Guid Repetido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40525/101)

A outra opção é usar uma chave `VARCHAR` com um código do cliente mais o identificador único incremental. Economiza espaço e não é um grande problema. Claro que é preciso garantir que em cada máquina não haverá repetição e que não exista duas máquinas usando o mesmo código. Se fizer errado pode criar dificuldades.

Considere fazer uma codificação binária deste código economizando espaço.

Uma otimização não muito necessária é gravar com `INT` ou até um `BIGINT` se achar que um dia terá milhões de linhas em cada máquina. O código seria calculado de acordo com o código do cliente. Vamos dizer que você queria provisionar até mil clientes, então o código sempre será um número incremental mais o código do cliente vezes 1 milhão, assim terá espaço para 1 milhão de linhas em cada linha.