# Dúvidas sobre o uso do tipo GUID no lugar de int

Tags: c#, desempenho

Vejo muitos modelos de sistemas na net onde campos Id são definidos com tipo GUID em vez de INT, como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public int Quantity { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; protected set; }
    public bool Active { get; protected set; }
}
```

- Qual a vantagem de usar GUID em vez de INT?
- Isso pode prejudicar a performance da Aplicação e/ou banco de dados?
- Tenho um sistema comercial que está sendo projetado ainda... Se eu usar GUIDS em vez de INTS em minhas tabelas, isso seria recomendado?

Um abraço a todos!

Comment: Possível duplicada de: [Devo utilizar GUID ou int como chave primária?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21907/devo-utilizar-guid-ou-int-como-chave-primária)

Answer (score 0):

`Guid` de uma forma simples é uma estrutura que representa um inteiro de 128 bits (16 bytes), permitindo representar 3.4028237*10^38 valores.
Um `int` dependendo do sistema é representado por 32 bits (4 bytes).
Na minha opinião depende do tamanho da sua base de dados.

Neste link, é melhor explicado:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22574/104651