# É uma prática ruim usar "Guid" e "int" para um mesmo banco?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, chave-primária, guid

Num projeto que estou desenvolvendo priorizo o uso de `Guid` para PK por causa da facilidade para mim, mas tem uma tabela que seria mais vantajoso usar `int`. Isto é errado?

Comment: Por questão de padrão eu escolheria entre um ou outro para todo o banco. A pergunta que o Maniero deixou o link na resposta dele responde bem o assunto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certo ou errado depende de contexto, não existe uma resposta mágica que pode sempre ou não pode nunca. Você tem que se perguntar que problemas espera ter? E porque precisa misturar as coisas? E por que usou GUID antes? Será que já não foi uma decisão equivocada? Ele tem vantagens, mas será que as desvantagens foram observadas? E por que agora precisa de outra forma?

Não tem problema usar chaves primárias com maneiras diferentes do ponto de vista do banco de dados, só precisa ver se é um problema para sua aplicação. Se não souber muito bem o que está fazendo com ela poderá ser um problema, e só você sabe disso (ou nem você).

Tem uma pergunta que fala mais sobre o assunto: [Devo utilizar GUID ou int como chave primária?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21907/101).